# Set discounted ticket price, with a floor of 0

Tags: python

Is there a shorter way to write this?

```
discounted_price = original_ticket_price - discount_value
if discounted_price < 0:
    discounted_price = 0
```

Comment: Why would you want a shorter way to write it if you don't mind? Are you golfing or something?

Comment: What's the connection to golfing? I just want to learn it the best, shortest way. Thought there might be a better way to write it.

Comment: It's just that usually when people ask for the shortest way to write something it's for [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)

Comment: Ahh, never heard of that. No, I actually just try to learn it the 'right' way.

Comment: Keep asking question then ;) Next time you post here, copy a more sizeable snippet of code, feedbacks will be way more interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the built-in [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
discounted_price = max(0, original_ticket_price - discount_value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python has a syntax for ternary since 2.5.

Syntax for it is `a if condition else b`, where condition is Truthy or Falsy( see Graipher comment).

You can rewrite your code like:

```
discounted_price = original_ticket_price - discount_value
discounted_price if discounted_price >= 0 else 0
```

Personnaly I find it harder to read but it is another way to write your code.

EDIT you can find more info on ternary in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/3729797)

Comment: `condition` does not have to be a boolean (`True` or `False`), a truthy or falsy value is sufficient (`[0]` and `[]` also work), as almost always in Python.